# How to replace dataframe values with numpy.nan using df.quantile(axis = 1)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the row-wise ascending rank of other values (via df.rank(ascending = True, axis = 1)) and I am trying to mask the values that are between the 30% and 70% quantiles.

```
df = {"A": [numpy.nan, 1, 2, 3, 2], "B": [2, 2, 1, 2, 1], "C": [1, 3, 3, 1, 3]}
df = pandas.DataFrame(df)
df["top_quantile"] = df.quantile(0.7, axis = 1)
df["bottom_quantile"] = df[["A", "B", "C"]].quantile(0.3, axis = 1)
df
     A  B  C  top_quantile  bottom_quantile
0  NaN  2  1           1.7              1.3
1  1.0  2  3           2.4              1.6
2  2.0  1  3           2.4              1.6
3  3.0  2  1           2.4              1.6
4  2.0  1  3           2.4              1.6
```

This would be trivial if the quantiles were static, but as in the example dataframe above, observations are added in over time so it's a bit trickier, and I have observations ranging from 8 valid columns to over 1000, so the quantile values are always changing. Is there a simple method of doing this in python that preferably isn't a for loop? My goal is something as below (Note that df.iloc[0, 0] was already nan):

```
     A    B  C  top_quantile  bottom_quantile
0  NaN  2.0  1           1.7              1.3
1  1.0  NaN  3           2.4              1.6
2  NaN  1.0  3           2.4              1.6
3  3.0  NaN  1           2.4              1.6
4  NaN  1.0  3           2.4              1.6
```

Currently, I have tried:

```
df[(df > df["bottom_quantile"]) & (df < df["top_quantile"])] = numpy.nan
```

which runs, but does not seem to do anything

```
df.mask((df >= df["bottom_quantile"]) | (df <= df["top_quantile"]), inplace = True)
```

which gives me the same problem as above.

and:

```
df.loc[:, (df >= df.count(axis = 1) * .3) & (df <= df.count(axis = 1) * .7)] = numpy.nan
```

which produces a "TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not iterable" (the index is pandas Timestamp in my actual example, if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the prettiest or most computationally efficient answer, but this worked:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pandas.Series(numpy.where((x < x.quantile(q = 0.7)) & (x > x.quantile(q = (0.3))), numpy.nan, x), index = x.index), axis = 1)
```